# Running Hyperledger Composer in multi-org multi-host environment

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I just finished setting up multi-org in Hyperledger Composer using the [official tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org). But that tutorial deals with only a single host. Now to add another org in another host, what are the changes that I need to incorporate to achieve this? Is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Have you tried searching the Web and other SO answers around this issue. Your question is very general and not focus in coding problem you need to solve

Comment: None of the tutorials/resources in Google clarifies how to go about this specific (multi-host multi-org) case. There are some answers in SO, but they do not specify how to setup. 

I just wanted to know if I can follow the tutorials for Fabric multi-host multi-org and carry out the usual Composer setup, or are there any special instructions for Composer?